# Does fscanf move the file pointer backwards?

Tags: c, file-pointer, ftell

These are the contents of my file, 'unsorted.txt' :

> 3 robert justin trump

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("unsorted.txt", "r");
    char n;
    printf("%d\n", ftell(f));
    fscanf(f, "%s", &n);
    int l = n - '0';
    printf("%d %d\n", l, ftell(f));
    return 0;
}
```

on execution it gives the following output:

```
0
3 -1
```

why did it return `-1` in second case? It should move from `0` to `1` right?

NOTE: the file can be opened, because then how would it print 0 in the first call and the first character from the file without being able to be opened?

Comment: Please test that `fopen` has not failed.

Comment: You should have got compiler warnings with this code. If you dint't get any, you probably want to figure out how to enable warnings and/or upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  fscanf(f,"%s",&n);
> ```

is very wrong, since you declared `char n;` (of only one byte). You got [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (and next time, be ashamed).

I recommend:

Test that `fopen` don't fail:

```
FILE *f = fopen("unsorted.txt","r");
if (!f)  { perror("fopen unsorted.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Declare a buffer of reasonable size (80 was the size of punched cards in the 1970s).

```
char buf[80];
```

clear it (you want [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)):

```
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

Then read carefully about [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Read that documentation several times. Use it with a fixed size and test its result:

```
if (fscanf(f, "%72s", buf) > 0) {
```

<sup>(72 was the usable size in PL/1 programs of punched cards; it is less than 80)</sup>

Don't forget to read documentation of other functions, including [ftell](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftell.3.html).

### Important hint:

compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), improve the code to get no warnings, **use the debugger** `gdb` to run  it step by step.

<sup>PS. As an exercise, find the possible content of `unsorted.txt` which made your initial program run correctly. Could you in that case predict its output? If not, why??</sup>

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You do not test the return value of `fopen()`. Calling `ftell()` with a `NULL` pointer has undefined behavior.  You cannot draw conclusions from observed behavior.
- `printf("%d\n", ftell(f));` is incorrect because the return value of `ftell()` is a `long`.  You should use the format `%ld`.
- `fscanf(f, "%s", &n);` is incorrect because you pass the address of a single `char` for `fscanf()` to store a null-terminated string. `fscanf()` will access memory beyond the size of the `char`, which has undefined behavior. Define an array of `char` such as `char buf[80];` and pass the maximum number of characters to store as: `fscanf(f, "%79s", buf);` and check the return value, or use `%c` to read a single byte.
- `int l = n - '0';` is not strictly incorrect, but it is error prone: avoid naming a variable `l` as it looks confusingly similar to `1`.
- `printf("%d %d\n", l, ftell(f));` is incorrect as the previous call to `printf`: use the conversion specifier `%ld` for the return value of `ftell()`.

Note also that the return value of `ftell()` on a text stream is not necessarily the byte offset in the file.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("unsorted.txt", "r");
    char c;

    if (f != NULL) {
        printf("%ld\n", ftell(f));
        if (fscanf(f, "%c", &c) == 1) {
            int diff = c - '0';
            printf("%d %ld\n", diff, ftell(f));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
3 1
```